# How do I get this piece of code to match through regex using variables?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find matches in some code using regex.

String I am using

```
"input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox] {"
```

To match this I added escape characters for every bracket:

```
"input\[type=radio\],input\[type=checkbox\] \{"
```

And I am running `.match` to find a match in a particular line of code:

```
"input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox] {".match(/input\[type=radio\],input\[type=checkbox\] \{/)
```

Which works. But when I turn them into variables, it doesn't.

```
str = "input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox] {"
code_to_match_against = "input\[type=radio\],input\[type=checkbox\] \{"

str.match(/#{code_to_match_against}/) # => nil
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might me wise to use a [CSS parser](https://github.com/alexdunae/css_parser) instead of hacking together regex if things get more complicated.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMarshall, hadn't seen that before. Its not getting more complicated than this, just using this for a couple of large files. But I will definitely bookmark that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double quotes in here:

```
code_to_match_against = "input\[type=radio\],input\[type=checkbox\] \{"
```

are eating your backslashes. Consider this:

```
>> code_to_match_against = "input\[type=radio\],input\[type=checkbox\] \{"
>> p code_to_match_against
"input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox] {"
```

So when you interpolate `code_to_match_against` into your regex, the regex engine thinks you're using two character classes:

```
/input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox] {/
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and character classes match only one character at a time (unless you append `*` or `+`).

Either double your backslashes to get them past the double quotes or use single quotes instead:

```
>> code_to_match_against = 'input\[type=radio\],input\[type=checkbox\] \{'
>> p code_to_match_against
"input\\[type=radio\\],input\\[type=checkbox\\] \\{"
>> puts code_to_match_against
input\[type=radio\],input\[type=checkbox\] \{
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks! I would have never figured that out. I didn't realize that single quotes and double quotes would affect it. Do you have any resource you recommend for me to fully understand the difference between the two?

Comment: @Fralcon: Maybe this [chunk of the book](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UD). I only use single quoted strings unless I'm going to be interpolating or needing `\n` and similar escape sequences; I picked up that habit years and years ago and it has served me well.